# Layout hds is not loaded expressJS

Tags: node.js, handlebars.js

in my router file I call a controller:

```
router.get('/selectedTest/:id', indexController.data_test);
```

the function in my controller:

```
exports.data_test = function(req, res) {

if (req.session && req.session.userId) {
    Test.findOne({_id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.params.id)}, (err, test) => {
        var data = [
            {label: "audio", value: test.audio.success},
            {label: "Micro", value: test.micro.success},
            {label: "Video", value: test.video.success},
            {label: "Input", value: test.input.success},
            {label: "Curseur", value: test.curseur.success}]

        res.render('selectedTest', {layout : 'layout',test: test, data:data,title: 'ProximityTools'});
    })}
}
```

but by accessing the page, the content is displayed without the layout knowing that I added the express.static middleware to my app and made it point to my directory with static assets. Also with the other views I do the same thing and I do not have this problem.

app.js:

```
app.engine('.hbs', expressHbs({defaultLayout: '', extname: '.hbs'}));
app.set('view engine', '.hbs');
// parse incoming requests
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/public')));
app.use('/', indexRouter);
app.use('/users', usersRouter);
app.use('/authentification',authRouter);
app.use('/inscription',inscriRouter);
app.use('/adminHome',homeRouting);
app.use('/SSHRoutingQualityBench',SSHRoutingQualityBench);
app.use('/SSHRoutingFPS',SSHRoutingFPS);
// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
next(createError(404));
});

// error handler
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
// set locals, only providing error in development
res.locals.message = err.message;
res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};
// render the error page
res.status(err.status || 500);
res.render('error');
 });
 module.exports = app;
```

[image]

Comment: could you add the expressjs configuration to understand where the problem might be?

Comment: you're talking about app.js or what?

Comment: Yes, the code of application file where you instantiated and configured expressjs

Comment: I updated the post, you can see

Comment: Thank you. Are the URL of the static files on the html page correct respect to the structure of the files in the public folder?

Comment: yes ! My page is displayed, only the layout is not

Comment: The code seems correct. Could you post the part of the html page where the scripts are included?

Comment: actually even I delete the content to see only the template ! it does not work, so I don't think the problem is there